# C++ - Polymorphic pointer to member functions

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I'm not very good at C++ (but I'm familiar with OOP/Java), but I have to create a game for my C++ class. I want to setup a kind of game engine like that used for Flash games written in ActionScript.

I wrote this two classes, where `Actor` is meant as a **base class** (probably will be abstract) and `Player` should actually implement it.

The problem is that I want to avoid duplicate code in the functions `addEventListener` and `handle` and re-declaring `_handlerMap`, since I want to achieve data hiding and such things.

The problem, I guess, is that `_eventMap` should contain `handler` values that can change class `Actor::*handler` and `Player::*handler`. Is it possible?

```
    class Actor {
    protected:
        typedef void(Actor::*handler)(Event);
        map<int, handler> _handlerMap;
    public:
        virtual void addEventListener(int ID, handler h) {
            _handlerMap.insert(std::make_pair(ID, h));
        };
        virtual void handle(int ID) {
            handler h = _handlerMap[ID];
            Event e;
            if (h)
                (this->*h)(e);
        }
        virtual void onUpdate(Event e) {
            cout << "Actor::onUpdate()" << endl;
        };
    };

class Player : public Actor {
    typedef void(Player::*handler)(Event);
    map<int, handler> _handlerMap;
public:
    void addEventListener(int ID, handler h) {
        _handlerMap.insert(std::make_pair(ID, h));
    };
    void handle(int ID) {
        handler h = _handlerMap[ID];
        Event e;
        if (h)
            (this->*h)(e);
    }
    void onKeydown(Event e) {
        cout << "Player::onKeyDown()" << endl;
    };
};
```

**I wish it was possible to declare Player as:**

```
class Player : public Actor {
        typedef void(Player::*handler)(Event);
 public:
        void onWhateverEvent(Event e);
 }
```

I hope you understand.

Comment: Do you want to allow other instances of `Actor` to register a handler? (i.e. does `addEventListener` have to be a public member?)

Comment: "The problem, I guess, is that `_eventMap`" -> do you mean `_handlerMap`?

Comment: The simplest solution I can think of is to use `std::function` and `std::bind`, available in C++11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like this (not tested):

```
class Dispatcher {
  public:
    virtual void dispatchEvent(Event*) = 0;
};

template <class C>
class DispatcherImpl : public Dispatcher
{
    typedef void(C::*handler)(Event* e);
    std::map<int, handler> _handlerMap;
    C* _owner;
  public:
    DispatcherImpl (C* c) : _owner(c) {}
    addEventListener(int ID, handler h) {
        _handlerMap.insert(std::make_pair(ID, h));
    }        
    void dispatchEvent(Event*)
    {
      handler h = handlerMap[e->id];
      if (h) (_owner->*h)(e);
    }
}
```

Now let each type `T` of actor own a `DispatcherImpl<T>`, and you are all set. You may also have e.g. `Player` inherit from `DispatcherImpl<Player>`.

Comment: `dispatchEvent` has to return something in order to e.g. let `Player` pass the event to `Actor` in case there's no special handler in `Player` for this event. Additionally, I'd rather use `map::find` instead of the `map::operator[]` to check if an element exists in the map.

Comment: @DyP: absolutely not. A `Player` *is* an `Actor`. What other `Actor` do you want to pass to? As for `map::find`, sure, use it. This snippet is strictly pseudocode, not to be used literally.

Comment: You mean only the derived types should inherit from `DispatcherImpl`? I thought you meant also `Actor` should derive from it; in that case you'd have to return e.g. a `bool` from `dispatchEvent` to indicate whether the event id has been found in the current `_handlerMap` or if it should be passed to the base class's dispatcher to be handled.

Comment: @DyP: the Player dispatcher has all the functions of the Actor. There is no need for chaining.

Comment: I tried this, but I can't make it work. The new "Player" class now has a "DispatcherImpl" member that I initialize in the Player's constructor as _dispatcher = new DispatcherImpl<Player>(this). When I write player.getDispatcher()->dispatchEvent(eventID, event), I get this error (in Visual Studio): can't convert from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>' to 'void (__thiscall Player::* )(int)'

Comment: Sorry, the error raises also if I call <code>addEventListener</code>, and there are few errors, not just that one. This is the link with the code: http://www.4shared.com/file/Cy36rMpU/main.html

Comment: I'm not sure how `std::string` has got there. This is probably a different question.

Comment: Anyway this is unfortunately a lot more complicated that I've described, you should probably scrap this and go with the `std::map<std::function<...>>` instead like DyP suggested. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: I end up with a map, memeber of Dispatcher, that maps ints with pointers to functions declared as f(T&, Event), where T is a template class. No need for std::function (I can't figure out how to use it). Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

What do you think of this? (Dispatcher is the same as DispatcherImpl above)

```
template <class T>
class Entity {
    T *_instance;
    Dispatcher<T> *_dispatcher;
public:
    Entity() {
        _instance = new T();
        _dispatcher = new Dispatcher<T>(_instance);
    }
};
class Actor {
    //attirbutes and methods
};
class Player : public Actor {
    //attirbutes and methods
};
```

To use it just:

```
Entity<Actor> *actor = new Entity<Actor>();
Entity<Player> *player = new Entity<Player>();
actor->getDispatcher()->addEventListener(0, &Actor::foo);
player->getDispatcher()->addEventListener(1, &Player::bar);
player->getDispatcher()->addEventListener(0, &Actor::foo); //inheritance
```